# clientLogin jQuery Ajax Process

Tags: jquery

I would like to auth a Google account using ClientLogin requested by a jQuery Ajax'Script.

How can I make this work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',
    //POST /accounts/ClientLogin HTTP/1.0
    ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    accountType: 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&amp;Email=jondoe@gmail.com&amp;Passwd=north23AZ'
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `accountType` is not a valid ajax setting. You should be passing the request's parameters using the setting `data`. Note also that [Google's ClientLogin documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps#ClientLogin) lists `accountType`, `Email`, `Passwd`, `service` and `source`as the required request parameters.

With that said the following code should work:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin",
    type:"POST", 
    data:{
        'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
        'Email': 'jondoe@gmail.com', 
        'Passwd': 'north23AZ', 
        'service': 'the_service_identifier', 
        'source': 'myCompany-myApp-version'
    },     
    success:function(data) { 
        // handle response
    }, 
    error:function(e) { 
        // handle error 
    }
});
```